# Will creating many new objects slow a game down? When is it appropriate to use “object pooling”?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

I'm making a small online game in Node and Javascript and after doing some reading about garbage collection, I'm not sure when it's considered bad practice to create new objects. I'm not just talking about using the "new" keyword, but I mean defining an object with multiple properties using curly braces.

I often use objects to pass information to functions as it is convenient. Is this slowing my game down? If it is, should I be worried about changing my approach or is the performance trade off not very large?

I've read about object pooling and ways to reuse objects to avoid creating new ones, is this something I should be implementing or is the GC considered good enough in most cases?

Comment: Using objects is totally fine - especially short-lived ones that might even be allocated on the stack. Use them for good code design and do not worry. Once you got a working application in good shape, use profiling to find out whether you have any problems, and then fix only those by closing memory leaks or optimising hot paths.

Comment: Note: If the properties created are fixed (`{a: .., b: ..}`) and not added to/deleted from later, implementations (like Node / V8) can _very efficiently_ handle the resulting objects — https://blog.usejournal.com/the-secrets-of-javascript-object-performance-optimization-5b648fc99f59

Answer (score 0):

Objects is common part of JS, of course you can use it as you need. Just don't forget couple of things:

1. Assign `null` or `undefined` to object properties when you don't need them anymore, or delete them: `delete object[property];`
2. Re-assign values of object, it is ok
3. GC will collect everything that has no references, so if you somewhere still reference to your object properties, they will be kept in memory.

```
var x = { 
  a: {
    b: 2
  }
}; 
// 2 objects are created. One is referenced by the other as one of its properties.
// The other is referenced by virtue of being assigned to the 'x' variable.
// Obviously, none can be garbage-collected.


var y = x;      // The 'y' variable is the second thing that has a reference to the object.

x = 1;          // Now, the object that was originally in 'x' has a unique reference
                //   embodied by the 'y' variable.

var z = y.a;    // Reference to 'a' property of the object.
                //   This object now has 2 references: one as a property, 
                //   the other as the 'z' variable.

y = 'mozilla';  // The object that was originally in 'x' has now zero
                //   references to it. It can be garbage-collected.
                //   However its 'a' property is still referenced by 
                //   the 'z' variable, so it cannot be freed.

z = null;       // The 'a' property of the object originally in x 
                //   has zero references to it. It can be garbage collected.
```

In general, you can read about GC and object references, [it's pretty easy and informative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

Comment: No, don't use the `delete` operator if you care about performance!

Comment: Yes, `delete` is slower then assigning `null` or `undefined` to object property. But finally it depends on program design, i.e. you doing some loops through object properties

Comment: Why would the delete operator hurt performance? Is the implementation not O(1) just like all the other methods such as get / put? That is assuming the values in the buckets are sparsely distributed.

Comment: See https://blog.usejournal.com/the-secrets-of-javascript-object-performance-optimization-5b648fc99f59 — just because objects _can_ be conceptualized as a simple dictionary does not mandate they are implemented so. Modern ECMAScript engines perform significant optimizations when given the chance..